# rich:jQuery not working on JS call

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have richfaces application. In the page, there is jQuery function defined:

```
<rich:jQuery timing="onJScall" name="updateUrlHash" selector="#conversationId" 
    query="alert('in jquery call');" />
```

Then I have some a4j:commandLink, which should call the function on completing ajax request.

```
<a4j:commandLink value="test" oncomplete="updateUrlHash(this)" />
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I know oncomplete works, because if I put there `alert('test');`, alert is shown. But when I try to call `updateUrlHash` function, it does not work. I checked in page source that function is there. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Query is called on object selected by jQuery selector. So in example like this, in javascript is it

```
jQuery(selector).alert('in jquery call');
```

This of course cannot work. So I need to call anything on selected element, and then I can do what I want:

```
query="hide(); alert('this works');"
```

In Javascript it is then (selected element is hidden anyway):

```
jQuery(selector).hide(); alert('this works');
```

Comment: Interesting. But can't you just define it as a plain vanilla JS function instead of using `rich:jQuery`?

Comment: I could, but I wanted to use plain JSF id (#conversationId), which in generated page is like `blabla:formbla:conversationId'. <rich:jQuery> handles it for me. And it was interesting problem anyway :)